# How to implement a symmetric autocorelation function?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to compute these values:

[image]

[image]

where `*` is the complex conjugate,`z[n]= exp( 1i* 2* pi* cumsum(wav_file_signal[n])/ wav_fs)`, `t' = t + int(wav_fs/4)`, `N` is the signal length and `t` takes values in the range.

So far I have this

```
import numpy as np

# Example usage
fs = 100  # Sample rate
Ts = 1 / fs  # Time step
N = 1000  # Length of the signal
t = np.arange(0, N) * Ts  # Time vector
f0 = 5  # Fundamental frequency of the signal

# Generate a noisy signal for testing
z = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(N)

tau_lim = 30
taus = np.arange(-tau_lim, tau_lim + 1)
alphas = round(fs / (4 * np.max(np.abs(z))))
tau_delta = round(fs / (4 * f0))

Rx = np.zeros((len(z), len(taus)))
R_1_result = np.zeros(len(z))
R_2_result = np.zeros(len(z))

z = np.exp(1j * 2 * np.pi * alphas * np.cumsum(z) / fs)


# Circular shift function
def circular_shift(signal, shift_amount):
    return np.roll(signal, shift_amount)


for i, tau in enumerate(taus):
    # R_1_backward_shift = z[:len(z) - abs(tau)]
    # R_1_forward_shift = z[abs(tau):]

    R_1_backward_shift = circular_shift(z, - abs(tau))
    R_1_forward_shift = circular_shift(z, abs(tau))

    R_1_length = len(R_1_forward_shift)  # R_1 and R_2 have the same length

    R_1_result = R_1_forward_shift * np.conj(R_1_backward_shift)

    # R_2_backward_shift = z[:len(z) - abs(tau) - tau_delta]
    # R_2_forward_shift = z[abs(tau) + tau_delta:]

    R_2_backward_shift = circular_shift(z, - abs(tau) - tau_delta)
    R_2_forward_shift = circular_shift(z, abs(tau) + tau_delta)

    R_2_length = len(R_2_forward_shift)

    R_2_result = R_2_forward_shift * np.conj(R_2_backward_shift)
```

Could you please someone evaluate the correctness of the code?

`R_z` is actually part of the kernel in equation (8) [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168414003053).

Comment: Please, avoid using images with transparent backgrounds. It's very hard to read in dark version of StackOverflow.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please see [tour] and [ask].

Comment: You should define and apply boundary conditions to `z`. In order to choose an appropriate boundary condition we need to know more about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I do not know how to start. What is reasonable assumption in the edges of the signal? Should we pad it with zeros or we should avoid the first element of the signal?

Comment: Well, it depends, what is the signal?

Comment: The signal is this `z= exp( 1i* 2* pi* cumsum(wav_file_signal)/ wav_fs);` Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. Try to contextualize it better. In any case, I don't think the core problem of this question is about programming and is probably a best fit in another SE community such as Computational Science, Data science or Cross validate.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the code? Any comments to improve it are very welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255833/discussion-between-phydev-and-thoth).